# Basicprimitives org chart node preview working wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

I successfully create a organizational chart with [BasicPrimitives-orgChart](http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=5&lang=en) but I have a problem with the node's preview when you do mouse hover.
Sometimes randomly gray "preview" node appears on the left of the screen.

Sometimes the preview shows correctly
[image: should be like this]

But somethimes appear the gray node
[image: gray preview node]

My fucntion to chart create

```
function buildChart() {
    var options = new primitives.orgdiagram.Config();
    var jsonString = $("[id$=txhDat]").val();
    var datos = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var arrayItem = [];
    for (index = 0; index < datos.length; index++) {
        var objUbica = datos[index];
        var item = new itemUbica(objUbica.cve, objUbica.name, objUbica.parent, objUbica.index);
        var itemFinal = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig(item);
        arrayItem[arrayItem.length] = itemFinal;
    }
    options.items = arrayItem;
    options.cursorItem = 0;
    options.templates = [getTemplateUbica()];
    options.onItemRender = onTemplateRender;
    options.hasButtons = primitives.common.Enabled.True;
    options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.False;
    options.onButtonClick = function (e, data) {

        switch (data.name) {
            case "move":
                $("[id$=]")
                dialogMoveOp(data.context.cveUbica, data.context.ubica);
                break;
        }
    };
    jQuery("#divChart").orgDiagram(options);
}
```

Also this happend just after the first render I dont manipulate anything in the DOM.
[image: See the initial div there (divChart)]

Comment: Do you remove DIV placeholder of widget from DOM? I mean the DIV you use to create orgDiagram?  I think it can happen because SVG element becomes invalid after widget HTML removal from DOM and putting it back, so widget cannot properly reuse elements and crashes. It is nice to see error log.

Comment: No i dont remove @Sergey, this happend even just after render.. let me put an image. Thanks for the replay Check out the image

Comment: Do you make any changes to widgets divs? It looks like callout's shadow is placed into top left corner of container. Is is possible that you made some changes to all DIV's on the page, I mean, you could change absolute positioning of call out div to relative, so it is placed in the wrong place.